# Warning: require_once(HTTP/Request2.php): failed to open stream:

Tags: 12.04

I have read many posts that tell me this is because pear is not installed. My issue is that it is installed and I have tried to re-install it without success.

I have my `php.ini` file set to

```
include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/php/pear'
```

I have logged into the system by ftp and the files exist and everything appears to be installed properly.

Where have I gone wrong.

FULL ERROR:

> Warning: require_once(HTTP/Request2.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/test.php on line 3 Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'HTTP/Request2.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/php/pear:/usr/share/PEAR') in /var/www/test.php on line 3

LINE 3: require_once('HTTP/Request2.php');

I have checked the installation of HTTP_Request2 and it is installed and up to date.

EDIT:  Could this be caused by some type of permissions?

Comment: Can you show me the code on line 3? It may be typo'd.

Comment: require_once('HTTP/Request2.php');

Answer (score 4):

Pear may be installed but pear is itself kind of package manager. Http_request2 has to be installed.

Compare http://pear.php.net/package/HTTP_Request2/redirected

On console try

```
sudo pear install HTTP_Request2
```

Comment: HTTP_Request2 is already installed and is the same as the released version

Comment: I have no ubuntu system at hand right now... so guessing...You already checked the inclusion path of your php.ini for existance of that file?! I would try filling in a phpinfo() for debugging and check if the value of php.ini applies to the skipt.

Comment: I dont see anything wrong This has to be a permissions problem but I dont even know where to start

Comment: I checked today my system (10.04 LTS).
My include path is
.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/php5:/usr/share/php/PEAR
(compare the capitalization)

Another solution would be to download the pear package manually and install it in your php path
http://download.pear.php.net/package/HTTP_Request2-2.1.1.tgz